# Geometry Nodes do not pop up

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm a complete beginner in terms of Blender, never worked with it before, so I'm probably missing something.

Anyway, I'm trying to make some models for a future game, and so I followed a tutorial for a texture that uses geometry nodes. That worked well, but today I tried to reopen the geometry nodes in Blender, but it just won't open. I spent an hour looking for the solution, but again no answers. I'm linking the photos of what it normally looks like on the Layout tab and what it looks like when I click on geometry nodes here, sorry if I'm missing something.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, what does not open? You need to create a new window and select the Geometry Node editor

Comment: Forgot to menrion but when i create a new project and go onto geometry nodes there it works, its really weird

Comment: It's not clear what you are missing

Comment: I just saw your comment, when i mean geometry nodes doesnt open i mean that the "coding" window for geometry nodes doesnt open, for some reason in all of the tutorials it opens just in this specifc project it doesnt work, even on new projects it works.

Comment: *Geometry Nodes* are a *Modifier*, so you would need to select this in the *Modifier Properties* tab.

Comment: The Layouts that you access on the top shelf are saved with the blend file. You changed your layout. The names of the layouts are only costmetic. Even though the layout you choose is named *Geometry Nodes* it can show any kind of window layout. You have changed the type of an area from a geometry node area to another editor type. To change the editor type, use the individual dropdown at the top left (header) of the area.

Comment: Thanks for the help, im pretty sure my issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

You may have changed your workspace before saving the file last time you worked on it. To open a geometry node editor, just look at the left end of any editor header, click the dropdown and choose "geometry node editor". You can learn the interface basics here : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/ -> section "User interface".